# Issues with list index after swapping first and last number in the list

Tags: python, list, swap

I am new to Python and with the swapping exercise, I cannot swap the first and last element of the list using the following code (the line with issue noted below).

```py
def swapList(list):
     
    first = list.pop(0)  
    last = list.pop(-1)
     
    list.insert(0, last) 
    list.insert(-1, first)  # this line is the issue.
    # It does not swap first to the last position in the list,
    # but instead place it just before the last number. If I change
    # it to list.append(first) then the issue is solved.
    # I cannot understand why.
     
    return list
```

Can you please help?

Comment: `.insert()` inserts the item _before_ the specified index position.  If you want to insert at the end, use `.insert(N, item)` where N is the length of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) says this about `list.insert`:

> `list.insert(i, x)`
> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element **before which to insert**, so `a.insert(0, x)` inserts at the front of the list, and `a.insert(len(a), x)` is equivalent to `a.append(x)`.

So this is what happens to the list:

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> first = xs.pop()
>>> 
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> first = xs.pop(0)
>>> last = xs.pop(-1)
>>> 
>>> xs
[2, 3, 4]
>>> 
>>> xs.insert(0, first)
>>> xs
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> xs.insert(-1, last)
>>> xs
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
>>>
```

The index you specify is "the index of the element before which to insert", so `insert(-1, 5)` inserts `5` before the last element. So if you change the line to `list.insert(len(list), last)`, your function will work as expected

---

However, there's a better way to do this. If you want to swap the first and the last item in the list, you can use tuple unpacking:

```py
xs[0], xs[-1] = xs[-1], xs[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `insert` method will insert the element to the left of the index you provide - `my_list.insert(0, 1)` would insert the value `1` to left of index `0` in `my_list`.

To add an item to the end of your list, use the `append` method instead: `my_list.append(1)`.

Also, don't call your list `list` - list is a reserved keyword in Python and should not be used to name a variable. You could instead use `my_list`, or , preferably, a name that describes what the list is for/the data it contains.

Answer (score 0):

list.pop removes elements from the list, making the list shorter. You can avoid this:

```
tmp = list[0]
list[0] = list[-1]
list[-1] = tmp
```

If you are required to use pop, then using insert to re-add that index to the list is needed:

```
tmp = list.pop(0)         # Remove 0 element from list, assign to tmp
list.insert(0, list[-1])  #Shifts elements by +1 for new 0th element
list[-1] = tmp            # Assign tmp to last element in list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def swaplist(list):     
    
    first = list.pop(0)    
    last = list.pop(-1) 
      
    list.insert(0, last)   
    list.append(first)    
      
    return list

list = [10 , 20 , 30 , 40 , 50 , 60]
 
print(swaplist(list))
```

Comment: The question already mentions that using `append` solves this issue. But the question is about why `insert(-1, last)` doesn't work.